# extract words in r factor

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataset like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
text = c("Update AV Line 204 to Los Angeles will be ...",
 "91 Line 700 to RiversideDowntown is delayed 15 minutes ...",
 "VC Line 102 to Los Angeles is delayed 1520 minutes ...",
 "Update AV Line 227 to Lancaster is terminated  Via Princessa ",
 "RIV Line 411 to Los Angeles is delayed 10 minutes ...",
 "SB Line 312 to San Bernardino is delayed up to ...",
 "SB Line 327 to Los Angeles is delayed up to 15..."), stringsAsFactors = T)

 df
```

and I need to extract key words in a new field so that the end product looks something like this:

```
> df
  text                                                            LinesExtracted
1 Update AV Line 204 to Los Angeles will be ...                   Line 204 to Los Angeles
2 91 Line 700 to RiversideDowntown is delayed 15 minutes ...      Line 700 to Riverside Downtown 
3 VC Line 102 to Los Angeles is delayed 1520 minutes ...          Line 102 to Los Angeles
4 UpdateAV Line 227 to Lancaster is terminated  Via Princessa     Line 227 to Lancaster 
5 RIV Line 411 to Los Angeles is delayed 10 minutes ...           Line 411 to Los Angeles
6 SB Line 312 to San Bernardino is delayed up to ...              Line 312 to San Bernardino
7 SB Line 327 to Los Angeles is delayed up to 15...               Line 327 to Los Angeles
```

Thanks.

Comment: The pattern is not 'regular' in the regex sense of the word IMO. You may be able to get a good answer if you establish a few stop words like "is" and "will" to consider non-city strings. Otherwise you will risk match errors. You could also include a known list of cities to match against.

Comment: Have a look at this link: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It looks like you're asking someone to write the code for you - that's not how SO works. Take a stab at the problem, if you run into problems as a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since regex can be difficult to read, I have split it into steps:

```
df$LinesExtracted <- gsub("^.*Line","Line",df$text)
df$LinesExtracted <- gsub(" will be .*$","",df$LinesExtracted)
df$LinesExtracted <- gsub(" is .*$","",df$LinesExtracted)
df$LinesExtracted <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])","\\1 \\2",df$LinesExtracted,perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! it doe the job perfectly.